$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| > 1$ does not imply the divergence of $\sum a_{n}$
Question
$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| > 1$ does not imply the divergence of $\sum a_{n}$.
Context
In baby rudin, chapter three, theorem3.34 says:-
a.) If $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| < 1 \implies \sum a_{n}$ converges.
b.) If  $\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| \ge 1$ for $n \ge n_0$ $\implies \sum a_{n}$ diverges.
There is an asymmetry in the above theorem, which wasn't there in root test. So I am looking for a counter example where
$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| > 1$ does not imply the divergence of $\sum a_{n}$.
Attempt
Does the following example work:-
Let $a_{n} = \{\frac{1}{2^{3}},\frac{1}{2^{2}},\frac{1}{4^{3}},\frac{1}{4^{2}},\frac{1}{6^{3}},\frac{1}{6^{2}} \ldots\}$. We note that $a_{n} \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Hence by comparison test $a_{n}$ converges and infact $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| = \infty$
Could somebody verify if this is fine?

Let $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{3^n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{3^n}.$ Then your limsup is $3.$

Basically, the $\limsup>1$ requires infinitely many $n$ such that $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|.$ But we can make those $n$ sparse enough to make the series converge. (Technically, that is only a necessary condition for $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n|\geq 1,$ to make it $>1,$ we need a little more.

@ThomasAndrews In the example you provided the limsup is 2, right? Could you help me see quickly how the series converges? It seems like I need to compare it with some geometric series ($\frac{2}{3^{n}}$?)

Yes, sorry, came up with a simpler example but failed to change the limsup value at the end.

We can even find examples where $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n|=+\infty.$ Let $a_{2n}=\frac1{n^3}, a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{n^2},$ for example.

Take any absolutely convergent series $\sum \alpha_m$ and any sequence $(r_m)$ with $r_n \ge 1$. Then also  $\sum \alpha_m/r_m$ is absolutely convergent. Define
$$a_n = \begin{cases} \alpha_m/r_m & n = 2m \\ \alpha_m  & n = 2m+1 \end{cases}$$
Then $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely and
$$\left\lvert \frac{a_{2m+1}}{a_{2m}} \right\rvert = r_m .$$
Thus
$$\limsup\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right\rvert  \ge \limsup r_m .$$
Now take your favorite sequence $(r_m)$ with $\limsup r_m > 1$. An eaxmple is $r_m = m$ in which case $\limsup\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right\rvert =\infty$.
